# Newbie confusion on hstore joins with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, controller, hstore

I have two postgres hstore based tables, `entity` and `info`, both of which look like this:

```
   Column   |           Type           |                           Modifiers
------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('entity__entities_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone | not null
 context    | hstore                   | default hstore((ARRAY[]::character varying[])::text[])
 data       | hstore                   | default hstore((ARRAY[]::character varying[])::text[])
```

so the query in SQL i want to perform is something like this:

```
SELECT e.context->'device' AS device, i.data->'location' AS location from entity AS e 
  LEFT JOIN info AS i ON e.context->'device' = i.context->'device'  
  WHERE e.data->'type'='chassis
```

So i have two paths:

- write the rails controllers referencing a VIEW on the database
- write some rails like queries using include, join etc.

i would really prefer to do the latter. however, i'm completely confused as to rails code to use.

my model is (i know i'm missing `belongs_to` etc, but i don't know how to make the relation with a hstore field):

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'entity'
  self.primary_key = 'id'
  attr_accessible :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :context, :data
  serialize :context, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
  serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end

class DeviceInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'info'
  self.primary_key = 'id'
  attr_accessible :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :context, :data
  serialize :context, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
  serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but ActiveRecord philosophy was to create a common layers for databases, and that query is very related to postgres, with serialized inner joins.

You can write a raw query to do that:

```
Device.find_by_sql("SELECT e.context->'device' AS device, i.data->'location' AS location from entity AS e LEFT JOIN info AS i ON e.context->'device' = i.context->'device' WHERE e.data->'type'='chassis")
```